# Use wifi only when necessary

Tags: wireless, networking, battery, optimization

To optimise my laptops battery life I would like to make it so that wifi gets turned on only when there is a process running which needs a network access.
For example when browser or transmission is started wifi turns on, but when I close them wifi also gets turned of.

Something like caffeine does for enabling and disabling screensaver when assigned processes are running.

Comment: Is it worth it?

I've toyed around with the very same idea time and again, but have arrived at the conclusion that it is not. That is to say: you're asking for more hassle and problems (on the day you figure you need the wifi again), than the potential energy / battery life saving you'll be able to realize. Any benchmark studies done on is, anyone??

Comment: I'm not sure myself is worth it. I just got new battery for my old eeepc and this idea again popped into my mind. It's more of one of those stupid ideas to make something unnecessary and complicated with intention to make your life easier. So maybe it is just stupid perfection instead of real gain. It's more of question why should you make your machine use energy in situations when you don't really need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no. You have something which is called laptop mode tools:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower

Above webpage does not mention support for wireless, but you can read about it here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/laptop-mode.conf.8.html

Take a look - maybe you will some settings which fit you.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it all a read and try.
Other option I just found is cuttlefish but that looks works more in triggering events
[link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cuttlefish-set-actions-reactions-automate-ubuntu/)
, instead of keeping some events working paralelly